# next button on sofkeyboard is not showing up in android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have few EditText views. I've added Action "next" to each one of them and action "Done" to the last one. It's behaviour is correct, the only problem is that there is no "next" string on enter button. It's showing just simple enter button, no "next" or "done" button.

**UPDATE**

Seems like it's working wrong on my htc one x(android 5.0.2) but i've tested it on samsung s3(android 4.4) and it works as intended

```
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"/>
```

[image]

Comment: try after removing `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`

Comment: @Tauqir i tried different cases removed inputType, removed ems, removed singleline. didn't help

Answer (score 0):

When you don't specify which is the next item that is associated to the next action, Android will try to guess what is the item that is probably the next. Sometimes it may guess it wrong, so it's better to always explicitly inform what is the next item associated to that element. You can do that with:

```
android:nextFocusForward="next_element_id"
```

or

```
android:nextFocusUp="up_element_id"
android:nextFocusDown="down_element_id"
android:nextFocusLeft="left_element_id"
android:nextFocusRight="right_element_id"
```

Hope this helps!